# Read a string value from data file - gnuplot

Tags: file-io, gnuplot

I am trying to read a string value from a data file, to be used as a input file identifier. The data file has multiple rows and two (tab-separated) columns - first column contains the description (string) and the second column contains the value (floats, strings). The data file `log.dat` is structured like this:

```
method  'u05'
observations    11
...
```

I want to read, for example, the 1st element of the 2nd column and store it in a variable, say, `id` and use it to identify an input file `data_-u05.dat` to be used for plotting:

```
splot '../out/data_-'.id.'.dat' using 1:2:3 notitle
```

I found this method but it reads the whole 1st row as `method   'u05'` instead of just the 2nd element:

```
file = '../out/log.dat'
id = system( sprintf("sed -n '1p' %s", file) )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried it and got an error:
`')' expected`

Comment: Ops, sorry, forgot the quotes: `id = system("awk '{print $2}' ../out/log.dat")`

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco This way, it is reading the full 2nd column into `id`. So I get the error when I try to use it as `splot '../out/data_'.id.'.dat' using 1:2:3 notitle` : `warning: Cannot find or open file "../out/data_-'u05' 11.dat"`. Also note that it is reading the string as `'u05'` instead of `u05` (without quotes).

Comment: OK, so you can use the following workaround (not pretty, but works): `id = system("awk '{print substr($2,2,3)}' ../out/log.dat")`. However, be aware that this assumes that all files have 3-character tags.

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco Sorry but this is also giving the same output as before, i.e., it reads the last 3 characters from all the rows instead of just the first row. So, the warning is also the same as before: `warning: Cannot find or open file "../out/data_-u05 11.dat"`. Edit: Also, this time, there is no quote around the tag `u05`. So the solution must be pretty close.

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco The method in the answer below works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more about awk than gnuplot, but this should work. It uses single-quote as a field separator in awk, prints field 2, and stops.

```
id = system("awk -F\\' '{print $2;exit}' ".file)
```

The single-quote needs to be escaped for the shell, and again in gnuplot. If you want to apply this to a specific line other than the first you can specify the line with `NR==`, eg

```
id = system("awk -F\\' 'NR==1{print $2;exit}' ".file)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. Just as a sidenote, `NR==1` reads the first line. And this also works with numeric values after removing `-F\\'`.